# How to delete widgets one by one

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I add an additional graph every time the button "open" is clicked.

I want to be able to delete graphs one by one with the "close" button, except for the first one.

I can only delete one chart.
Maybe this is what I'm using "splitter", wrong.
I tried to print "print(self.lay.count())" all the time it turns out two.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart

mas =[1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.65, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 2.3, 1.5, 1.35, 2.52, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.7, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1,
              1.33, 1.15, 1.55, 1.92, 1.64, 1.91, 1.33, 1.71, 1.5, 1.35, 1.22, 1.77, 1.7, 1.87, 2.0, 1.55, 1.73, 2.1]
x = len(mas)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.open = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.open.setText("Open")
        self.open.clicked.connect(self.open_clicked)
        self.close = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.close.setText("Close")
        self.close.clicked.connect(self.close_clicked)

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.open)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.close)

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.lay.addWidget(self._chart_view)
        self.lay.insertLayout(0, self.hbox)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()

        for i in range(0, len(mas)):
            self._line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, mas[i]))

        self._chart.addSeries(self._line_serie)
        self._chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self._chart.legend().hide()
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)

    def open_clicked(self):
        number = self.lay.count() - 1
        self.item = self.lay.itemAt(number)
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        for w in (self.item.widget(), self._chart_view):
            self.splitter.addWidget(w)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
        for i in range(0, len(mas)):
            self._line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, mas[i]))
        self._chart.addSeries(self._line_serie)
        self._chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)

        print(self.lay.count())


    def close_clicked(self):
        self._chart_view.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "self._chart_view" stores the last QChartView so when deleting it with deleteLater it will point to an unreserved memory causing errors to want to delete it since it is already deleted. On the other hand, I don't see the need to use a QVBoxLayout, but a QSplitter is enough, and the last widget can be accessed using the `QSplitter::widget()` method.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.open_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open")
        self.open_btn.clicked.connect(self.add_chartview)
        self.close_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close")
        self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.remove_chartview)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.open_btn)
        hbox.addWidget(self.close_btn)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addLayout(hbox)
        lay.addWidget(self.splitter, stretch=1)

        self.add_chartview()

    def add_chartview(self):
        chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        chart = QtChart.QChart()
        line_serie = QtChart.QLineSeries()
        for i, value in enumerate(mas):
            line_serie.append(QtCore.QPointF(i, value))
        chart.addSeries(line_serie)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart_view.setChart(chart)
        self.splitter.addWidget(chart_view)

    def remove_chartview(self):
        count = self.splitter.count()
        if count > 1:
            w = self.splitter.widget(count - 1)
            if w is not None:
                w.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Only in the penultimate line you need to replace "widget" with "w"